# what is difference between "sleep" and "wait"

Tags: php, block, sleep, wait

what is difference between `while(true) {sleep(1);}` and `while(true) {$queue.wait();}`? which one will take the CPU cost?

i think the `sleep` execute will use CPU to calculate and compare the conditions; 
at the other side, `wait` is a blocking call, will not use CPU until something `notify` to wait it up

am i understood wrong? and how to implement `wait` in lower level? with `sleep` or other?

```
// example(in PHP):
while (true) {
    // do something 
    // until some conditions become true
    sleep(1);
}

while (true) {
    $data=$sock.accept(); // block until data response
    // $queue.wait(); // also block until data enqueue
    // do something
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what `wait` is -- most likely it's also a busy wait. `$obj.wait()` is also very suspect -- that's not PHP syntax for calling a method on an object, it does something entirely different.

Comment: Yep. Sounds like you're confusing PHP code and some JavaScript code.

Comment: thanks, sorry about bad example. how about `$sock.accept()`?

Comment: i had modify the subject and question, is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

`while(true)` is basically `while(true==true)`, which as you said, is an infinite loop!

Wait can be implemented using the sleep() function, yes.

```
while(condition=true)
{
sleep(x);
}
```

Where condition is what you are checking for (Page load, download finish, etc), and x is how long you want it to wait, in seconds.